# How to identify new element appear on the exixting webpage using selenide

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenide

I did automation for a React web application.
Looking for help to achieve the below scenario,

I'm Clicking a button on the page. After clicking the button there is an image load to the page.
To load the image it will take around 5 seconds.
Also, image load to newly created element,
(In the page before click there is no `div` for the image load, but after I clicked on the button it appears on the page, and inside of that `div` image loaded).
In my method I'm trying to verify the image is loaded after the button click.
But always it returns `NoSuchElementException`.

Note: If I search for the element manually using the above xpath, the element getting highlighted

Below are the ways I tried out

```
1.
public static boolean waitElementPresent(SelenideElement element) {
        try {
            element.should(Condition.appear, Duration.ofSeconds(TIME_OUT));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

2.
public static boolean waitElementPresent(SelenideElement element) {
        try {
            element.should(Condition.visible, Duration.ofSeconds(TIME_OUT));
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Nither of way success,
**Can anyone tell me to achieve this using Selenide-java**
Here some sample load :
[image]

Comment: Any Url available?

Comment: Possible causes:

1. missing switch to frame
2. incufficient wait time
3. wrong locator
4. any combination of above mentioned

Comment: @theNishant No this is in local host,

Comment: @pburgr I checked above cases you mentioned but still same

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, using "ifs" and "try/catch" in tests is a bad practice.

1. Why do you need to return boolean from `waitElementPresent`? What are you going to do with this boolean?
2. If the element should be there - just check it appears:

```
public static void waitElementPresent(SelenideElement element) {
   element.should(Condition.appear, Duration.ofSeconds(TIME_OUT));
}
```

See
https://selenide.org/2019/12/02/advent-calendar-how-to-abuse-selenide/

Comment: I do an assertion if the element available I need to return true If the element does not appears need to be return false. I tried with `Condition.appear` as I mentioned in tried that, But I wouldn't succeed, (I put debug point before method execution and wait until element loads, even though it got failed)

Comment: Why do you need to return `true` or `false`? How will you use this `true` or `false`?

Comment: In page object layer it returns true or false and in the test layer (In step definition I do the assertion.)

Comment: @RajithKariyawsam Exactly! You don't really need to return a boolean and do an assertion with it. Selenide method `should(...whatever...)` IS the assertion.